# Change a value in a specific column (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I simply want to change a value in a specific colomn

```
gene     scaf    GC     other
gene1    3456    78      other1
gene2    7898    56      other 2
gene3    5667    23      other 3
```

etc
and I want to add at each gene name the following number: _number1 
and get:

```
gene             scaf    GC      other
gene1_number1    3456    78      other1
gene2            7898    56      other 2
gene3            5667    23      other 3
```

thanks all.

Comment: You can use `df['gene'] = df['gene'] + '_number1'`

Comment: In fact, it has to be specific to the value in the column because I do not want to change all my value in the column gene, I changed the exemple to be more clear sorry;

Comment: So need for all `gene1` add `_number1` string ?

Comment: The gene1 is present just once, so I only want to add _number for this specific gene yep.

Comment: So `df.loc[df['gene'] == 'gene1', 'gene'] += '_number1'` is what looking for?

Comment: It join all values `gene1` with `_number1`

Comment: Thanks you for your help it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add string by condition:

```
df.loc[df['gene'] == 'gene1', 'gene'] += '_number1'

print (df)
            gene  scaf  GC    other
0  gene1_number1  3456  78   other1
1          gene2  7898  56  other 2
2          gene3  5667  23  other 3
```

Comment: @Benjamin - Glad can help!